# Android SQLite database lifecycle

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite, lifecycle

I'm new to android. I want to ask about SQLite database lifecycle. Basicaly, I want to include the insert data method and viewing data method in the main class (which basicaly called 1st when we open the app). Then I'm going to make some update to the database in another activity. What I want to ask is, when I'm going to open the app for the next time, which data that will be showed? Is it the 1st data that I inserted with insert method OR the updated one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand exactly your question. So I hope this will answer it. There are 4 operations, you should implement: create, read, update, delete. For example when you have a contact table with id, name, phone number then you can create (John, 012345). If you then call the read method with id 1, you will get (John, 012345). But if you update this before you read it, you obviously get the updated item - the database didn't delete anything when you close the activity. I highly recommend you to create a new class to handle those crud-operations, because you will get crazy, when you wanna change the update operation and must search it in every single line from your app. I also recommend you to read this blog. It saved me a lot of time:
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: can I put the insertData() method in the Main class?

Comment: you must get the context of the application to create the sqliteopenhelper / databasehandler - class. so you must call something like: DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

Comment: I've tested it now. You can put it in your inserData() method. then just replace "this" with "getApplication()" and you should be fine: DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplication());

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question,

my answer is -> You should see the updated data, because Db is same throughout the app.

Answer (score 0):

The data that will be shown is the updated one , because SQL operations are immediate. It is very unlikely that onUpdate() will not update the database until and unless it encounters any error. you can see that itself using a CursorLoader attached with your cursor after running a query command. This can be done in an activity just displaying the contents of the database.

For database operations, It is beneficial to use Content Providers cause then you can extend your apps to widgets, share data with other apps etc.